# Twitter Bootstrap popover not working with IE9

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-9, popover

I have an issue with the twitter bootstrap popover. I have downloaded and installed the most recent package (`twitter-bootstrap-v2.2.0-2-g3b3dd3a`) I made a simple html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Twitter Bootstrap Popover with placement option Example</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Creating Modal Window with Twitter Bootstrap">
    <link href="twitter-bootstrap/docs/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style> a { margin-left : 400px; } </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Example of creating Popover with Twitter Bootstrap with placement option</h2>
      <div class="well">
        <a href="#" id="example" class="btn btn-success" rel="popover" data-content="It's so simple to create a tooltip for my website!" data-original-title="Twitter Bootstrap Popover">hover for popover</a>
      </div>
      <div class="well">
        <a href="#" id="example_left" class="btn btn-success" rel="popover" data-content="It's so simple to create a tooltop for my website!" data-original-title="Twitter Bootstrap Popover">hover for popover</a>
      </div>
      <div class="well"> <a href="#" id="example_top" class="btn btn-success" rel="popover" data-content="It's so simple to create a tooltop for my website!" data-original-title="Twitter Bootstrap Popover">hover for popover</a> </div>
      <div class="well"> <a href="#" id="example_bottom" class="btn btn-success" rel="popover" data-content="It's so simple to create a tooltop for my website!" data-original-title="Twitter Bootstrap Popover">hover for popover</a> </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="twitter-bootstrap/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="twitter-bootstrap/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> $(function () { $("#example").popover(); $("#example_left").popover({placement:'left'}); $("#example_top").popover({placement:'top'}); $("#example_bottom").popover({placement:'bottom'}); });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that, using IE9, the buttons aren't formatted properly, while in Chrome they appear just fine

Here how they are displayed in IE9:
[image]

Here in Chrome:
[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the position of the buttons, or the general appearance? The latter is probably not really fixable in IE.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with popovers, but with a lousy browser standards compliance. IE9 doesn't natively support all the CSS attributes that Bootstrap uses. I've had some success using CSS3PIE to help with this. http://css3pie.com

The good news is that IE10 seems to be very standards-compliant, and it renders text and images beautifully to boot. 2-3 more years of IE hell and we'll be in a new golden age.

Comment: yes.  In 2-3 more years we will be in a new golden age of wishing for everyone to hurry up and upgrade to IE11.